# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^1 x^p (1-x)^{-1}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck on the following question from Folland's Real Analysis book (chapter 2, problem 31b).

> Derive the following formula by expanding part of the integrand into an infinite series and justifying the term-by-term integration.  For p > -1,
>   $$
> \int_0^1 x^p (x-1)^{-1} dx = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(p+k)^2}
> $$

I can expand the second factor as a power series, but I don't see how that helps me.  Worse yet, I don't even see how this can be correct.  Taking for example $p=0$, I get

$$
\int_0^1 (x-1)^{-1} dx = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{du}{u} = - \int_{0}^1 \frac{dy}{y}
$$

which as far as I know doesn't converge.  I'm not sure then if Folland meant for $p \in (-1,0)$, or for $p > -1, p \neq 0$, or if the problem is just incorrect.  Or maybe I am just missing something obvious.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Graphing $x^p/(x-1)$, it would appear to be meant $p\in (-1,0)$

Comment: @JacobMazor Can you provide more reasoning?  The problem when integrating is near $x=1$, and near 1, $x^p$ approaches 1 for $p \in (-1,0)$, so it still doesn't seem likely that that $x^p/(x-1)$ is integrable over $(0,1)$.

Comment: You are missing a factor of $\log x$: The integral as it appears in (my copy of ) Folland is $\int_0^1 x^p(1-x)^{-1}\log x\,dx$. (Actually, Folland uses the letter $a$ rather than $p$.)

Comment: @JohnDawkins I must have a different version of Folland.  I will try your version and see if that works out.

Comment: Clearly a typo since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^p}{x-1}\,dx$ is blatantly divergent due to the simple pole at $x=1$ of the integrand function.

Answer (score 2):

> As John Dawkins stated in a comment following the OP post, the OP is missing a factor of $\log(x)$ in the integrand.  Without that factor, the integrand has a non-removable singularity at $x=1$ and the integral diverges.   We now proceed to evaluate the "corrected integral" that has the factor $\log(x)$ in the integrand.

---

For $p>-1$ we have

$$\int_0^1 x^{p+n}\log(x)\,dx=-\frac{1}{(p+n+1)^2}\tag1$$

Next, summing $(1)$ over $n$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(p+n)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{p+n}\log(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^p(1-x^{N+1})}{1-x}\,\log(x)\,dx\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Noting that for $x\in [0,1]$, have $\left|\frac{x^p(1-x^{N+1})}{1-x}\,\log(x)\right|\le -2\frac{x^p}{1-x}\log(x)$ and that $0\le \int_0^1 -2\frac{x^p}{1-x}\log(x)\,dx<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that we can interchange the limit with the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ yields

$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(p+n)^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x}\,\log(x)\,dx$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Was this answer useful?  Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.